# Unity AR library (like ARCore, vuforia or EasyAR) that can work with ipcamera

Tags: library, augmented-reality, unity

I am searching for a Unity AR library which can work with an IP camera through an HTTPS stream (or something similar), not just an integrated or directly connected camera. It should be used in desktop application. I have not found anything yet so I am open to workarounds with these libraries as well.